# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'short-crypt' Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, encryption, package, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to use short-crypt into my angular project and I am getting the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'short-crypt' in '/project'
```

I did

```
npm i short-crypt
```

Also added the following scripts to my index.html file:

```
<script  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/magiclen/ts-short-crypt/dist/short-crypt.min.js"> </script>
```

I import short-scrypt into my project as:

```
import {ShortCrypt} from "short-crypt";
```

and create a new variable in the component:

```
  shortCrypt: ShortCrypt
```

then I setup and use it as:

```
 this.shortCrypt = new ShortCrypt(`test`);
const compressed =  this.shortCrypt.encrypt(Some_string);
```

I did not add it to the App Module as I couldn't find an import for it. Anyone know how I can resolve this error?